# MS Teams - Messaging Extension SSO - Claims

Tags: botframework, single-sign-on, microsoft-teams

I am trying to implement SSO for a messaging extension inside Teams. The issue I'm running into is to do with missing consent, **User.Read**.

I'm using the teams SDK to generate an ID token using the `microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken` function in the messaging extension, which I will exchange server side, but this does not include the User.Read claim (So the user can not consent to it) which I need for later graph calls. I have tired adding this to the “claims” property in the `AuthTokenRequest` but it doesn’t seem to do anything.

```js
    microsoftTeams.authentication.getAuthToken({
      claims: ["https://graph.microsoft.com/user.read"],
      successCallback: (token: string) => {
        setToken(token);
      },
      failureCallback: (message: string) => console.log("Failed:", message)
    });
```

I am confident that SSO is set up correctly as it works using a bot message if I follow the app-sso sample found here: https://github.com/OfficeDev/Microsoft-Teams-Samples/tree/main/samples/app-sso/nodejs

Asking the user to log in before opening the messaging extension also correctly request consent to User.Read. I am using is node.js for the server which made this document harder to understand:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/messaging-extensions/how-to/enable-sso-auth-me

Any help would be greatly appreciated on how to get the User.Read claim when performing SSO in messaging extensions.

Cheers

Comment: Could you please go through this [52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/javascript_nodejs/52.teams-messaging-extensions-search-auth-config) node.js sample and let us know if that helps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way to get the additional scope I required (User.Read) was to have the server return a certain error on invalid grants.

When the client got this error, call the `microsoftTeams.authentication.authenticate` function to open another page in a pop out window.

On this page, I used the [MSAL npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@azure/msal-browser) to have the user consent to the User.Read permissions

```js
// There is more than just this call, but the documentation is pretty good
const request: RedirectRequest = {
    scopes: [`https://graph.microsoft.com/User.Read`],
    loginHint
};
msalClient.loginRedirect(request);
```

To make this silent, I got the `loginHint` from the teams context and passed that to the request

```js
microsoftTeams.getContext(context => {
    start(context.loginHint ?? "");
});
```